# Regression Model in Python not meaningful

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression

I want to make a regression model in python which is between energy ratings Vs. the price of houses and **see whether the energy ratings affect the price of house or not**

[Dataset](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pSOrn2cfdVL6am2N_kFchdAUFvhr2AUv/view?usp=sharing) looks like:

[image]

Here is the model implemented using linear regression.

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

# Initialise and fit linear regression model using `statsmodels`
model = smf.ols('price ~ energyrating', data=df)

model = model.fit()
```

```
model.params

#price=2.004943e+06 + (-.913381e+05)*energyrating

Intercept       2.004943e+06
energyrating   -3.913381e+05
dtype: float64
```

```
# Predict values
pred = model.predict()

# Plot regression against actual data
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
plt.plot(df['energyrating'], df['price'], 'o')           # scatter plot showing actual data
plt.plot(df['energyrating'], pred, 'r', linewidth=2)   # regression line
plt.xlabel('Energy ratings')
plt.ylabel('Price')
plt.title('Energy ratings Vs. Price')

plt.show()
```

[image]

This model doesn't give any meaningful knowledge, For proper graph, I have squared the `energyrating` since the values were small comparing to `price` but still not proper. Am I missing out on any important points?

How can I create a model which gives meaningful relationship between `energy rating` and `price` ?

*Open to other models suggestions* Thanks in advance

Comment: The conclusion I have from analysing the dataset you provided is that there is almost always no connection between `price` and `energyrating` (that's basically the interpretation of slope close to zero). Note that you have a lot of points with relatively low price regardless of the evergy rating. The regression line you got is the correct result.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. Just one question, what could be other models or algorithms that could help me find a relationship . Since you said, ‘no connection’ I want to confirm that is there any model or chart could help me find a relationship.?

Comment: If no linear relation, there could be some other kind of relation. This looks a bit gaussian here ! But this is more a math/stat question than programming. Could be asked here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You want a model or algorithm that finds a relationship but I said there is no relationship, at least I don't see any. Choosing other method should yield the same result. You might want to try polynomial regression or neural network, but the result will not be 'meaningful' as you said in your question. You ask _How can I create a model which gives meaningful relationship_ but you can't get that when in fact there is no any relationship. You might want to get to know `pandas-profiling` module which reports about correlations and provides other interesting information about the dataframe.

Comment: Answering about the gaussian. Yes, but only if you had the percentage of the top priced points. Again - note that you have lots and lots of relatively low priced houses.

Answer (score 1):

You missed this code, so you should put it between "model = smf.ols('price ~ energyrating', data=df)" and "model = model.fit()".
Maybe...

```
#Divide test data and training data into 7 and 3
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

model = model.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you. I am getting this error `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

Comment: For this code,  ```import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
# Initialise and fit linear regression model using `statsmodels`
model = smf.ols('price ~ energyrating', data=df)
x=df['price']
y-df['energyrating']
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

model = model.fit(x_train, y_train)
```